# Replace wildcards in a binary string avoiding three identical consecutive letters

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, backtracking

Given a string S of length N, return a string that is the result of replacing each `'?'` in the string S with an `'a'` or a `'b'` character and does not contain three identical consecutive letters (in other words, neither `'aaa'` not `'bbb'` may occur in the processed string).

Examples:

```
Given S="a?bb", output= "aabb"

Given S="??abb", output= "ababb" or "bbabb" or "baabb"

Given S="a?b?aa", output= "aabbaa"
```

**1<=n<= 500000**

I solved the problem using backtracking, but my solution is slow and won't work for greater N values, is there a better approach?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237507/discussion-on-question-by-infernus-85-replace-wildcards-in-a-binary-string-avoid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible Implementation for [rules in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69317310/5980430).

---

This implementation is

- left-to-right
- single pass with 2 look-behind and 1 look-ahead (despite initial checking)
- `O(n)` time complexity
- can be `O(1)` space complexity since the context is at most 4 character
- does **not** check for invalid Input

---

First merge the rules

- `a?? => ab?`

  - `a??b => abab` (`a??b => ab?b => abab`)
  - `a??a => abba`
  - `a???????????????????b => ab??????????????????b`
- `ba?b => baab`
- `^a?b => ^aab`
- `a? => ab` otherwise (also imply `a??`)

  - `aa? => aab`
  - `a?a => aba`
  - `aa?b => aabb`

---

Then setup the boundary conditions.

The rule need the string *not* start with `?`s (not necessary if simply  fill them in another pass)

- `^?? => a?` (as if we prepend a `b`)
- `^?a => ba`

The rule need 2 look back in case of `a?b` so I simply pre-apply it to prevent the check inside primary loop

- prefill `^a?b => ^aab`

---

The Code ([WandBox link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hHaRww9JeaLPdEo7))

```
char inverse(char c){return c=='a'?'b':'a';}

std::string solve(std::string s){
   
   /// boundary conditions
   
   if(s.size()<3){
      for(auto& c:s) if(c=='?') c='b';
      return s;
   }
   
   if(s.starts_with("??")) s[0]='a'; // ?? => a? // not really necessary if use another pass to fill prefix '?'s
   if(s.starts_with("?a")  || s.starts_with("?b"))  s[0]=inverse(s[1]); // ?a => ba // not really necessary as above
   if(s.starts_with("a??") || s.starts_with("b??")) s[1]=inverse(s[0]); // not really necessary, just to prevent access s[-1]
   if(s.starts_with("a?b") || s.starts_with("b?a")) s[1]=s[0]; // ^a?b => aab
   
   /// primary loop
   
   for(auto curr=s.data(); curr!=s.data()+s.size(); ++curr)
   if(*curr=='?'){
      if(curr[-1]!=curr[1] && curr[-2]==curr[1]) *curr=curr[-1]; // ba?b => baab
      else *curr = inverse(curr[-1]); // a? => b (rule coaslesing)
   }
    
   return s;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

first of all `x??y` with more than 1? would always pass

- `a??b => abab` (produce no increase of length on both side, *no impact* at following)
- `a??a => abba` (no impact)
- `a???????????????????b => ab?????????????????ab`

so you only need to consider the case with single `?`

- `aa? => aab` (no other possibility)
- `a?a => aba` (no impact)

so the only problem comes to `a?b`

- `aa?b => aabb` (as describe in `aa?`)
- `ba?b => baab` (no impact)
- `^a?b` => `^aab` (only for start, no impact)

---

You did at most 2 look-back and 2 look-ahead so this is a `O(n)` solution,

If it can contain invalid input, simply run another `O(n)` check

<sub>I added a [possible implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69327913/5980430) in my another answer)</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237510/discussion-on-answer-by-apple-apple-replace-wildcards-in-a-binary-string-avoidin).

Answer (score 10):

(Please also see my greedy [O(n) time, O(1) space solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69327013/2034787) that includes random tests, comparing with MTO's code.)

The `O(n)` dynamic program has four states: a character is either `a_first`, `a_second`, `b_first` or `b_second`. Let `dp[i]` represent the possibility of creating a valid string up to index `i`. Then:

```
dp[i][a_first] = True
dp[i][a_second] = True
dp[i][b_first] = True
dp[i][b_second] = True
  where i < 0

if s[i] == '?':
  dp[i][a_first] = dp[i-1][b_first] or dp[i-1][b_second]
  dp[i][a_second] = dp[i-1][a_first]
  dp[i][b_first] = dp[i-1][a_first] or dp[i-1][a_second]
  dp[i][b_second] = dp[i-1][b_first]
  
else if s[i] == 'a':
  dp[i][a_first] = dp[i-1][b_first] or dp[i-1][b_second]
  dp[i][a_second] = dp[i-1][a_first]
  dp[i][b_first] = False
  dp[i][b_second] = False
  
else:
  dp[i][a_first] = False
  dp[i][a_second] = False
  dp[i][b_first] = dp[i-1][a_first] or dp[i-1][a_second]
  dp[i][b_second] = dp[i-1][b_first]

where i ≥ 0
```

To get the strings, we can follow the paths backwards that maintain True throughout and keep the consecutive character constraint.

Python code:

```py
def f(s):
  dp = [[None] * 4 for _ in range(len(s))]

  def get_dp(i, j):
    return True if i < 0 else dp[i][j]

  for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == '?':
      dp[i][0] = get_dp(i-1, 2) or get_dp(i-1, 3)
      dp[i][1] = get_dp(i-1, 0) 
      dp[i][2] = get_dp(i-1, 0) or get_dp(i-1, 1)
      dp[i][3] = get_dp(i-1, 2)
  
    elif s[i] == 'a':
      dp[i][0] = get_dp(i-1, 2) or get_dp(i-1, 3)
      dp[i][1] = get_dp(i-1, 0)
      dp[i][2] = False
      dp[i][3] = False
  
    else:
      dp[i][0] = False
      dp[i][1] = False
      dp[i][2] = get_dp(i-1, 0) or get_dp(i-1, 1)
      dp[i][3] = get_dp(i-1, 2)

  # Build the output
  result = []

  i = len(s) - 1
  need = None

  while i >= 0:
    if dp[i][0] and need != 'b':
      result.append('a')
      need = None if (len(result) == 1 or result[-2] == 'b') else 'b'
      i-= 1
    elif dp[i][1] and need != 'b':
      result.extend(['a', 'a'])
      need = 'b'
      i -= 2
    elif dp[i][2] and need != 'a':
      result.append('b')
      need = None if (len(result) == 1 or result[-2] == 'a') else 'a'
      i -= 1
    elif dp[i][3] and need != 'a':
      result.extend(['b', 'b'])
      need = 'a'
      i -= 2
    else:
      return ""

  return "".join(reversed(result))
```

Output:

```py
strs = [
  "a?bb", # "aabb"
  "??abb", # "ababb" or "bbabb" or "baabb"
  "a?b?aa", # "aabbaa"
  "?bb?",
  "aa?bb", # NO SOLUTION
  "aa??aa", # "aabbaa"
  "ab???bb?",
  "????",
  "??",
  "?????",
  "??????"
]

for s in strs:
  print("%s\n%s\n" % (s, f(s)))

"""
a?bb
aabb

??abb
baabb

a?b?aa
aabbaa

?bb?
abba

aa?bb


aa??aa
aabbaa

ab???bb?
abbaabba

????
abaa

??
aa

?????
aabaa

??????
baabaa
"""
```

Comment: I am not very comfortable with dynamic programming. I'm still trying to learn it. But you code seems to work. Does your code work for if all the characters are '?'

Comment: @infernus-85 yup. Just added four examples.

Comment: What do the four dp states dp[i][0], dp[i][1], dp[i][2], dp[i][3] represent?

Comment: @infernus-85 the four dp states dp[i][0], dp[i][1], dp[i][2], dp[i][3] represent whether or not the character at index `i` of the result can be a "first a," a "second a," a "first b," or a "second b" in that order. For example, a character can only be a "second a" if the previous character can be a "first a" -- try to follow similar common-sense logic to understand the conditions for the other states.

Answer (score 3):

An iterative backtracking solution.

- `isValid` only checks whether inserting a char `c` at position `pos` would create an issue, without iterating over the whole string;
- maintain a variable `int dir = +-1` to know whether we're moving forward or backwards in the string (this is only important so that we know in which direction to move when skipping over a non-`?` character in the original string);
- forest of `if/else if/else` to decide where we're at (non-`?` to skip, or fresh `?` going forward, or already tried `a`, or already tried both `a` and `b`);
- `solve` has a boolean return value which is `true` if a solution was found (`pos == s.length()`), or `false` if no solution was found (`pos == (unsigned int) -1`).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool isValid(char c, std::string const &s, unsigned int pos)
{
    return ((pos < 2 || s[pos - 2] != c || s[pos - 1] != c)
         && (pos < 1 || pos + 1 >= s.length() || s[pos - 1] != c || s[pos + 1] != c)
         && (pos + 2 >= s.length() || s[pos + 1] != c || s[pos + 2] != c));
}
bool solve(std::string const &in, std::string &out)
{
    unsigned int pos = 0;
    int dir = 1;
    out = in;
    while (pos < in.size())
    {
        if (in[pos] != '?')  // nothing to do: keep moving (forward or backward)
        {
            pos += dir;
        }
        else if (out[pos] == '?')  // going forward, will try 'a' then 'b'
        {
            dir = 1;
            if (isValid('a', out, pos))
            {
                out[pos] = 'a';
                pos += dir;
            }
            else if (isValid('b', out, pos))
            {
                out[pos] = 'b';
                pos += dir;
            }
            else
            {
                dir = -1;
                pos += dir;
            }
        }
        else if (out[pos] == 'a' && isValid('b', out, pos)) // going backward, already tried 'a'
        {
            out[pos] = 'b';
            dir = 1;
            pos += dir;
        }
        else // already tried everything: backtrack
        {
            dir = -1;
            out[pos] = '?';
            pos += dir;
        }
    }
    return (pos == in.size());
}

int main(void)
{
  std::vector<std::string> ins  = {"a?bb", "??abb", "a?b?aa", "aa?bb"};
  std::vector<std::string> outs = {"", "", "", "", ""};
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ins.size(); ++i)
  {
      if (solve(ins[i], outs[i]))
          std::cout << ins[i] << "  -->  " << outs[i] << std::endl;
      else
          std::cout << ins[i] << "  -->  NO SOLUTION" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a?bb  -->  aabb
??abb  -->  ababb
a?b?aa  -->  aabbaa
aa?bb  -->  NO SOLUTION
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the optimized version of the backtracking solution. I learned a lot from this.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing [@appleapple's O(N) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69317310/1509264) in JavaScript (but should be relatively simple to port to C++):

```js
let solve = (str) => {
  let opposite = {"a":"b","b":"a"};
  let curr_idx = 0;
  let output = [];
  
  let lookahead  = (x) => ((curr_idx+x<0)||(curr_idx+x>=str.length)?null:str[curr_idx + x]);
  let lookbehind = (x) => (curr_idx-x<0?null:output[curr_idx - x])
  let matches    = (x,y) => (x == y || x == null || y == null);
  let is_replacement = (x) => (x == '?');
  
  while ( curr_idx < str.length )
  {
    let curr = lookbehind(1) || 'b';
    let i = 0;
    let next = lookahead(i);
    while (is_replacement(next))
    {
      ++i;
      next = lookahead(i);
    }
    
    if (next == null)
    {
      // Found the end of the string.
      // Append characters opposite to the previous for each ?
      for (; i > 0; --i)
      {
        curr = opposite[curr];
        output.push( curr );
      }
      break;
    }

    if (i > 1)
    {
      // Found multiple successive ?s
      // Handle the first half of the ?s by
      // Append alternating characters from the previous character.
      let j = 0;
      for (; j < i/ 2; ++j)
      {
        curr = opposite[curr];
        output.push( curr );
      }
      // Then handle the second half of the ?s
      // append alternating characters to the next character after the ?s.
      for (; j < i; ++j)
      {
        output.push( (j%2) == (i%2) ? next : opposite[next] );
      }
    }
    else if (i == 1)
    {
      // Found a single ?
      let prev = lookbehind(2);
      if (curr == prev && curr == opposite[next] && next == lookahead(2))
      {
        // No solution.
        return null;
      }
      if (curr == prev || matches(curr, next))
      {
        output.push( opposite[curr] );
      }
      else
      {
        output.push( curr );
      }
    }

    if ( next != null )
    {
      // Output the next non-? character.
      output.push( next );
    }
    curr_idx += i + 1;
  }
  
  return output.join("");
};

let tests = [
  "?",
  "a?",
  "a??",
  "a???",
  "b?",
  "b??",
  "b???",
  "a?a",
  "a?b",
  "b?a",
  "b?b",
  "a??a",
  "a??b",
  "b??a",
  "b??b",
  "aa?",
  "ba?",
  "a?bb",
  "?bb?",
  "??abb",
  "a?b?aa",
  "ab???bb?",
  "aa?bb",
];

for ( let test of tests )
{
  console.log( `${test} -> ${solve(test)}` );
}
```

---

## Update - All possible solutions

It is possible to reduce the problem to 10 rules operating from left-to-right on the string looking at a maximum window of 6 characters (2 look-behind and 4 look-ahead) such that the rules can generate all possible solutions for the string:

```
Rules:
0: ss?dd_ -> No solution
1: __??ss -> __?dss
2: _s?s__ -> _sds__
3: ss?___ -> ssd___
4: __?ss_ -> __dss_
5: DS?DS_ -> DSsDS_ | DSdDS_
6: DS??sD -> DSsdsD | DSddsD | DSdssD
7: Ds??dS -> DsdsdS | DssddS
8:  ^??X_ ->  ^s?X_ |  ^d?X_
9: Ds??X_ -> DssdX_ | Dsd?X_

Notations:
 s: Same character.
 d: The opposite of the same character.
 S: Either the same character or the end-of-the-string.
 D: Either the opposite of the same character or the start- or end-of-the-string.
 _: Any character or the start- or end-of-the-string.
 ?: A character to replace.
 X: Either a character to replace or the end-of-the-string.
 ^: The start-of-the-string.
```

(Note: Rule 1 is essentially the same as rule 4 but handles the later replacement character first.)

This leads to the JavaScript code:

```js
function* solve(
  str,
  i = 0,
  depth = 0
)
{
  let data        = Array.from(str);
  let chr         = (n) => (n < 0 || n > data.length ? null : data[n]);

  let lookbehind2 = chr(i - 2);
  let lookbehind1 = chr(i - 1);
  let current     = chr(i);
  let lookahead1  = chr(i + 1);
  let lookahead2  = chr(i + 2);
  let lookahead3  = chr(i + 3);

  const DEBUG     = (rule) => {
    if (false)
    {
      console.log(`${"".padStart(depth)}Rule ${rule}@${i}: ${str} -> ${data.join("")}`)
    }
  };

  let stepForward = (steps) => {
    for (let n = 0; n < steps; ++n)
    {
      ++i;
      lookbehind2 = lookbehind1;
      lookbehind1 = current;
      current     = lookahead1;
      lookahead1  = lookahead2;
      lookahead2  = lookahead3;
      lookahead3  = chr(i + 3);
    }
  }

  let isSolved = (ch) => (ch == 'a' || ch == 'b');
  let isSame = (ch1, ch2) => (isSolved(ch1) && ch1 == ch2);
  let opposite = (ch) => ({"a":"b","b":"a"}[ch]);
  let isOpposite = (ch1, ch2) => (isSolved(ch1) && ch1 == opposite(ch2));
  let isEndOfString = (ch) => (ch == null);
  let isStartOfString = (ch) => (ch == null);

  while( !isEndOfString(current) )
  {
    if (current != '?')
    {
      stepForward(1);
      continue;
    }
    
    // Rules:
    //  0: ss?dd_ -> No solution
    //  1: __??ss -> __?dss
    //  2: _s?s__ -> _sds__
    //  3: ss?___ -> ssd___
    //  4: __?ss_ -> __dss_
    //  5: DS?DS_ -> DSsDS_ | DSdDS_
    //  6: DS??sD -> DSsdsD | DSddsD | DSdssD
    //  7: Ds??dS -> DsdsdS | DssddS
    //  8:  $??X_ ->  $s?X_ |  $d?X_
    //  9: Ds??X_ -> DssdX_ | Dsd?X_
    //
    // Notations:
    //   s: Same character.
    //   d: The opposite of the same character.
    //   S: Either the same character or the end-of-the-string.
    //   D: Either the opposite of the same character or the start- or end-of-the-string.
    //   _: Any character or the start- or end-of-the-string.
    //   ?: A character to replace.
    //   X: Either a character to replace or the end-of-the-string.
    //   $: The end-of-the-string.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    
    // Rule 0: ss?dd_ -> No solution
    if (
      isSame(lookbehind2, lookbehind1)
      && isSame(lookahead1, lookahead2)
      && lookbehind1 != lookahead1
    )
    {
      DEBUG(0);
      return;
    }

    // Rule 1: __??ss -> __?dss
    if (lookahead1 == '?' && isSame(lookahead2, lookahead3))
    {
      data[i + 1] = lookahead1 = opposite(lookahead2);
      DEBUG(1);
    }
      
    // Rule 2: _s?s__ -> _sds__
    if (isSame(lookbehind1, lookahead1))
    {
      data[i] = current = opposite(lookahead1);
      DEBUG(2);
      stepForward(2);
      continue;
    }

    // Rule 3: ss?___ -> ssd___
    if (isSame(lookbehind2, lookbehind1))
    {
      data[i] = current = opposite(lookbehind1);
      DEBUG(3);
      stepForward(1);
      continue;
    }

    // Rule 4: __?ss_ -> __dss_
    if (isSame(lookahead1, lookahead2))
    {
      data[i] = current = opposite(lookahead1);
      DEBUG(4);
      stepForward(3);
      continue;
    }

    // Rule 5: DS?DS_ -> DSsDS_ | DSdDS_
    if (lookahead1 != '?')
    {
      data[i] = current = "a";
      DEBUG(5);
      for (solution of solve(data.join(""), i + 2, depth + 1))
      {
        yield solution;
      }
      data[i] = current = "b";
      DEBUG(5);
      for (solution of solve(data.join(""), i + 2, depth + 1))
      {
        yield solution;
      }
      return;
    }

    // Rule 6: DS??sD -> DSsdsD | DSddsD | DSdssD
    if (
      isSame(lookbehind1, lookahead2)
      || (isStartOfString(lookbehind1) && isSolved(lookahead2))
    )
    {
      data[i]   = current    = lookahead2;
      data[i+1] = lookahead1 = opposite(lookahead2);
      DEBUG(6);
      for (solution of solve(data.join(""), i + 3, depth + 1))
      {
        yield solution;
      }
      data[i]   = current    = opposite(lookahead2);
      data[i+1] = lookahead1 = opposite(lookahead2);
      DEBUG(6);
      for (solution of solve(data.join(""), i + 3, depth + 1))
      {
        yield solution;
      }
      data[i]   = current    = opposite(lookahead2);
      data[i+1] = lookahead1 = lookahead2;
      DEBUG(6);
      for (solution of solve(data.join(""), i + 3, depth + 1))
      {
        yield solution;
      }
      return;      
    }
    
    
    // Rule 7: Ds??dS -> DsdsdS | DssddS
    if (isOpposite(lookahead2, lookbehind1))
    {
      data[i]   = current    = lookahead2;
      data[i+1] = lookahead1 = opposite(lookahead2);
      DEBUG(7);
      for (solution of solve(data.join(""), i + 3, depth + 1))
      {
        yield solution;
      }
      data[i]   = current    = opposite(lookahead2);
      data[i+1] = lookahead1 = lookahead2;
      DEBUG(7);
      for (solution of solve(data.join(""), i + 3, depth + 1))
      {
        yield solution;
      }
      return;      
    }

    // Rule 8:  $??X_ ->  $s?X_ |  $d?X_
    // Rule 9: Ds??X_ -> DssdX_ | Dsd?X_
    if (lookahead2 == "?" || isEndOfString(lookahead2))
    {
      if (isStartOfString(lookbehind1))
      {
        data[i] = current = "a";
        DEBUG(8);
        for (solution of solve(data.join(""), i + 1, depth + 1))
        {
          yield solution;
        }
        data[i] = current = "b";
        DEBUG(8);
        for (solution of solve(data.join(""), i + 1, depth + 1))
        {
          yield solution;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        data[i] = current = opposite(lookbehind1);
        DEBUG(9);
        for (solution of solve(data.join(""), i + 1, depth + 1))
        {
          yield solution;
        }
        data[i]   = current    = lookbehind1;
        data[i+1] = lookahead1 = opposite(lookbehind1);
        DEBUG(9);
        for (solution of solve(data.join(""), i + 2, depth + 1))
        {
          yield solution;
        }
      }
      return;
    }
    
    throw `Invalid state ${data.join("")}`;
  }
  
  yield data.join("");       
}        

let tests = [
  "?",
  "??",
  "???",
  "a?",
  "a??",
  "a???",
  "b?",
  "b??",
  "b???",
  "a?a",
  "a?b",
  "b?a",
  "b?b",
  "a??a",
  "a??b",
  "b??a",
  "b??b",
  "aa?",
  "ba?",
  "a?bb",
  "?bb?",
  "?a",
  "?aa",
  "??aa",
  "???aa",
  "????aa",
  "?ab",
  "??ab",
  "???ab",
  "????ab",
  "a?b?aa",
  "ab???bb?",
  "aa?bb",
  "a?b?a?bb",
  "?a?b?aa",
];

for ( let test of tests )
{
  console.log( `${test} -> ${[...solve(test)]}` );
}
```

If you want a single solution then you should be able to take only the first match for each rule and implement that in a O(N) time and O(1) memory solver.

---

## Update 2: C++ solution

Same algorithm as the JavaScript solution but uses a stack of partial solutions (rather than the JavaScript solution of recursively calling generator functions).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class PartialSolution
{
  public:
    const std::string partial_solution;
    const int position;

    PartialSolution(
      std::string const &solution,
      const int pos
    ):
      partial_solution(solution),
      position(pos)
    {}
};

class Solver
{
    const bool DEBUGGING = false;
    std::string str;
    int position;
    
    char lookbehind2;
    char lookbehind1;
    char current;
    char lookahead1;
    char lookahead2;
    char lookahead3;
    
    char get_character(int pos) const
    {
      if ( pos < 0 || pos >= str.length() )
      {
        return '\0';
      }
      return str[pos];
    }
    
    void load_partial_solution(PartialSolution const &ps)
    {
      str = ps.partial_solution;
      position = ps.position;
      
      lookbehind2 = get_character(position - 2);
      lookbehind1 = get_character(position - 1);
      current     = get_character(position + 0);
      lookahead1  = get_character(position + 1);
      lookahead2  = get_character(position + 2);
      lookahead3  = get_character(position + 3);

      if (DEBUGGING)
      {
        std::cout << "Load @" << position << ": " << str << "\n";
      }
    }

    void step_forward(int n)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      {
        ++position;
        lookbehind2 = lookbehind1;
        lookbehind1 = current;
        current     = lookahead1;
        lookahead1  = lookahead2;
        lookahead2  = lookahead3;
        lookahead3  = get_character(position + 3);
      }
    }
    
    bool is_solved(char ch) const
    {
      return ch == 'a' || ch == 'b';
    }

    bool is_same(char ch1, char ch2) const
    {
      return is_solved(ch1) && ch1 == ch2;
    }

    char opposite(char ch) const
    {
      switch(ch)
      {
        case 'a': return 'b';
        case 'b': return 'a';
        default:
             return '\0';
      }
    }
    
    bool is_opposite(char ch1, char ch2) const
    {
      return is_solved(ch1) && ch1 == opposite(ch2);
    }

    bool is_end_of_string(char ch) const
    {
      return ch == '\0';
    }

    bool is_start_of_string(char ch) const
    {
      return ch == '\0';
    }
    
    void DEBUG(int rule, bool pushback = false) const
    {
      if (DEBUGGING)
      {
        std::cout << (pushback?"Save: ":"") << "Rule " << rule << "@" << position << ": " << str << "\n";
      }
    }
  public:
    std::list<std::string> solve(std::string const&);
};


std::list<std::string> Solver::solve(std::string const& data)
{
  std::list<PartialSolution> partial_solutions = { PartialSolution(data, 0) };
  std::list<std::string> solutions = {};
  
  while( !partial_solutions.empty() )
  {
    load_partial_solution( partial_solutions.back() );
    partial_solutions.pop_back();
    
    while( !is_end_of_string(current) )
    {
      if (current != '?')
      {
        step_forward(1);
        continue;
      }

      // Rules:
      //  0: ss?dd_ -> No solution
      //  1: __??ss -> __?dss
      //  2: _s?s__ -> _sds__
      //  3: ss?___ -> ssd___
      //  4: __?ss_ -> __dss_
      //  5: DS?DS_ -> DSsDS_ | DSdDS_
      //  6: DS??sD -> DSsdsD | DSddsD | DSdssD
      //  7: Ds??dS -> DsdsdS | DssddS
      //  8:  $??X_ ->  $s?X_ |  $d?X_
      //  9: Ds??X_ -> DssdX_ | Dsd?X_
      //
      // Notations:
      //   s: Same character.
      //   d: The opposite of the same character.
      //   S: Either the same character or the end-of-the-string.
      //   D: Either the opposite of the same character or the start- or end-of-the-string.
      //   _: Any character or the start- or end-of-the-string.
      //   ?: A character to replace.
      //   X: Either a character to replace or the end-of-the-string.
      //   $: The end-of-the-string.
      // -----------------------------------------------------------

      // Rule 0: ss?dd_ -> No solution
      if (
        is_same(lookbehind2, lookbehind1)
        && is_same(lookahead1, lookahead2)
        && lookbehind1 != lookahead1
      )
      {
        DEBUG(0);
        goto no_solution;
      }

      // Rule 1: __??ss -> __?dss
      if (lookahead1 == '?' && is_same(lookahead2, lookahead3))
      {
        lookahead1 = opposite(lookahead2);
        str[position+1] = lookahead1;
        DEBUG(1);
      }
      
      // Rule 2: _s?s__ -> _sds__
      if (is_same(lookbehind1, lookahead1))
      {
        str[position] = current = opposite(lookahead1);
        DEBUG(2);
        step_forward(2);
        continue;
      }

      // Rule 3: ss?___ -> ssd___
      if (is_same(lookbehind2, lookbehind1))
      {
        str[position] = current = opposite(lookbehind1);
        DEBUG(3);
        step_forward(1);
        continue;
      }

      // Rule 4: __?ss_ -> __dss_
      if (is_same(lookahead1, lookahead2))
      {
        str[position] = current = opposite(lookahead1);
        DEBUG(4);
        step_forward(3);
        continue;
      }

      // Rule 5: DS?DS_ -> DSsDS_ | DSdDS_
      if (lookahead1 != '?')
      {
        str[position] = current = 'b';
        DEBUG(5, true);
        partial_solutions.emplace_back(str, position + 2);
        str[position] = current = 'a';
        DEBUG(5);
        step_forward(2);
        continue;
      }

      // Rule 6: DS??sD -> DSsdsD | DSddsD | DSdssD
      if (
        is_same(lookbehind1, lookahead2)
        || (is_start_of_string(lookbehind1) && is_solved(lookahead2))
      )
      {
        str[position]   = current    = opposite(lookahead2);
        str[position+1] = lookahead1 = lookahead2;
        DEBUG(6, true);
        partial_solutions.emplace_back(str, position + 3);
        str[position]   = current    = opposite(lookahead2);
        str[position+1] = lookahead1 = opposite(lookahead2);
        DEBUG(6, true);
        partial_solutions.emplace_back(str, position + 3);
        str[position]   = current    = lookahead2;
        str[position+1] = lookahead1 = opposite(lookahead2);
        DEBUG(6);
        step_forward(3);
        continue;
      }

      // Rule 7: Ds??dS -> DsdsdS | DssddS
      if (is_opposite(lookahead2, lookbehind1))
      {
        str[position]   = current    = opposite(lookahead2);
        str[position+1] = lookahead1 = lookahead2;
        DEBUG(7, true);
        partial_solutions.emplace_back(str, position + 3);
        str[position]   = current    = lookahead2;
        str[position+1] = lookahead1 = opposite(lookahead2);
        DEBUG(7);
        step_forward(3);
        continue;
      }

      // Rule 8:  $??X_ ->  $s?X_ |  $d?X_
      // Rule 9: Ds??X_ -> DssdX_ | Dsd?X_
      if (lookahead2 == '?' || is_end_of_string(lookahead2))
      {
        if (is_start_of_string(lookbehind1))
        {
          str[position] =  current = 'b';
          DEBUG(8, true);
          partial_solutions.emplace_back(str, position + 1);
          str[position] = current = 'a';
          DEBUG(8);
          step_forward(1);
          continue;
        }
        else
        {
          str[position]   = current    = lookbehind1;
          str[position+1] = lookahead1 = opposite(lookbehind1);
          DEBUG(9, true);
          partial_solutions.emplace_back(str, position + 2);
          str[position]   = current    = opposite(lookbehind1);
          str[position+1] = lookahead1 = '?';
          DEBUG(9);
          continue;
        }
      }

      throw std::invalid_argument(str);
    }
    
    solutions.push_back(str);
    
    no_solution:;
  }
  
  return solutions;
}

void run_test(
  Solver &solver,
  std::string const &test
)
{
  std::cout << test << " -> ";
  std::list<std::string> solutions = solver.solve(test);
  int size = solutions.size();
  for (const auto& solution : solutions)
  {
    std::cout << solution;
    if (--size != 0)
    {
      std::cout << ", ";
    }
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  std::list<std::string> tests = {
    "?",
    "??",
    "???",
    "a?",
    "a??",
    "a???",
    "b?",
    "b??",
    "b???",
    "a?a",
    "a?b",
    "b?a",
    "b?b",
    "a??a",
    "a??b",
    "b??a",
    "b??b",
    "aa?",
    "ba?",
    "a?bb",
    "?bb?",
    "?a",
    "?aa",
    "??aa",
    "???aa",
    "????aa",
    "?ab",
    "??ab",
    "???ab",
    "????ab",
    "a?b?aa",
    "ab???bb?",
    "aa?bb",
    "a?b?a?bb",
    "?a?b?aa",
  };
  Solver solver = Solver();
  for (const auto& test : tests)
  {
    run_test(solver, test);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the algorithm a little better. What are the lookahead and lookbehind functions doing? From what I understand, this algorithm is based on the sliding window. The look ahead and look behind are finding two characters that are not wildcards & are in between wildcards. Am I right?

Comment: @infernus-85 and MTO, I believe I fixed a bug in my greedy O(n) time, O(1) space solution. I include code at the end that tests 1000 random (but valid) inputs. Both this and my greedy approach seem to pass. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69327013/2034787 And here: https://ideone.com/N9vXFa

Comment: @infernus-85 Look-behind looks at prior characters in the string at a relative offset to the current position being solved. Look-ahead looks at characters in the string at a relative offset to the first non-replacement character after the current position being solved.

Comment: @infernus-85 and MT0, apple apple implemented their solution. It's genius -- so short! See [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I751J4KytDVnJdAU) (and here is a python version with random testing as well https://ideone.com/oGwDef)

Comment: @גלעדברקן I've looked at the c++ code and now I've finally understood the algorithm. The only problem I was having was the start of the string. Once  we deal with all the starting permutations, then it's easy from there.

Comment: @infernus-85 great! Their answer deserves the accepted status.

Comment: @infernus-85 Updated with a C++ algorithm that generates all possible solutions for each input.

Comment: @MT0 just a note, your implementation doesn't return null for already invalid input (like `aaa`)

Comment: @appleapple It assumes that the input is currently valid; if you want to assume that the input may be invalid then add a simple check when `current != '?'` for 3 consecutive identical letters and return (or `goto no_solution` in the C++ algorithm) rather than stepping forward and continuing.

Comment: @MT0 I just mean the first snippet you return null for `aa?bb` while not consistent with `aaa`.

Comment: @appleapple `aaa` is invalid input as there are 3 identical sequential characters and you do not need to solve the input to know that as it is already invalid. `aa?bb` does not have 3 identical sequential characters and it is not until you solve it that you find it is invalid for all possible outputs. As I said in my previous comment, it is a trivial fix to check for 3 identical sequential non-replacement characters but the assumption was that input like `aaa` will never be given. If it will then add the simple check for it.

Comment: @MT0 Oh it's fine, my own implementation doesn't even check for any invalid input. as I said, it's just a note (that I found a little inconsistent).

Answer (score 2):

The greedy version below seems to work. This way, we could have constant space aside from one output string. Can someone help find a counter example? I wrote this idea before implementing the straightforward dynamic program (see [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69316546/2)). Try to maintain sequences of two of the same character as much as possible.

The last section of the code below includes random testing with this and [MTO's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69322213/2034787).

Python code:

```py
def is_valid(s):
  if not s:
    return True
  char = "x"
  count = 0
  for c in s:
    if c != char:
      char, count = c, 1
    else:
      count += 1
      if count == 3:
        return False
  return True


# My greedy solution
def f(s):
  if len(s) == 2:
    return s.replace('?', 'a')
    
  aa = ['a', 'a']
  bb = ['b', 'b']

  out = []
  i = 0
  a, b = 0, 0

  while i < len(s):
    if s[i] == 'a' or (s[i] == '?' and b == 2):
      if s[i] == 'a' and a == 2:
        if s[i-3:i-1] == "??":
          out[i-3], out[i-2] = out[i-2], out[i-3]
          a -= 1
        else:
          return ""
      out.append('a')
      a, b = a + 1, 0
      i += 1
    elif s[i] == 'b' or (s[i] == '?' and a == 2):
      if s[i] == 'b' and b == 2:
        if s[i-3:i-1] == "??":
          out[i-3], out[i-2] = out[i-2], out[i-3]
          b -= 1
        else:
          return ""
      out.append('b')
      a, b = 0, b + 1
      i += 1
    elif i == len(s) - 1:
      out.append('a' if b else 'b')
      i += 1
    elif i == len(s) - 2:
      if s[i+1] == '?':
        out.extend(aa if b else bb)
      else:
        out.append('a' if b else 'b')
        out.append(s[i+1])
      i += 2
    elif s[i+1] == '?':
      if a:
        out.append('a')
        a, b = a + 1, 0
      else:
        out.append('b')
        a, b = 0, b + 1
      i += 1
    elif s[i+1] == 'a':
      if a or b < 2:
        out.append('b')
        a, b = 0, b + 1
      else:
        out.append('a')
        a, b = a + 1, 0
      i += 1
    elif s[i+1] == 'b':
      if b or a < 2:
        out.append('a')
        a, b = a + 1, 0
      else:
        out.append('b')
        a, b = 0, b + 1
      i += 1

  return ''.join(out)


# https://stackoverflow.com/a/69322213/2034787
# Code by MTO
def solve(_str):
  opposite = {"a": "b", "b": "a"}
  curr_idx = 0
  output = []
  
  lookahead  = lambda x: None if ((curr_idx + x < 0) or (curr_idx + x >= len(_str))) else _str[curr_idx + x]
  lookbehind = lambda x: None if curr_idx-x< 0 else output[curr_idx - x]
  matches = lambda x, y: x == y or x == None or y == None
  is_replacement = lambda x: x == '?'
  
  while curr_idx < len(_str):
    curr = lookbehind(1) or 'b'
    i = 0
    next = lookahead(i)
    while is_replacement(next):
      i += 1
      next = lookahead(i)
    
    if next == None:
      # Found the end of the string.
      # Append characters opposite to the previous for each ?
      for _ in range(i, 0, -1):
        curr = opposite[curr]
        output.append( curr )
      break

    if (i > 1):
      # Found multiple successive ?s
      # Handle the first half of the ?s by
      # Append alternating characters from the previous character.
      j = 0
      while j < i / 2:
        curr = opposite[curr]
        output.append( curr )
        j += 1
      # Then handle the second half of the ?s
      # append alternating characters to the next character after the ?s.
      while j < i:
        output.append( next if (j%2) == (i%2) else opposite[next] )
        j += 1
  
    elif i == 1:
      # Found a single ?
      prev = lookbehind(2)
      if curr == prev and curr == opposite[next] and next == lookahead(2):
        # No solution.
        return None

      if curr == prev or matches(curr, next):
        output.append( opposite[curr] )
      else:
        output.append( curr )

    if next != None:
      # Output the next non-? character.
      output.append( next )

    curr_idx += i + 1
  
  return ''.join(output)


strs = [
  "a?bb", # "aabb"
  "??abb", # "ababb" or "bbabb" or "baabb"
  "a?b?aa", # "aabbaa"
  "?bb?",
  "aa?bb", # NO SOLUTION
  "aa??aa", # "aabbaa"
  "ab???bb?",
  "????",
  "??",
  "?????",
  "??????",
  "?",
  "a?",
  "a??",
  "a???",
  "b?",
  "b??",
  "b???",
  "a?a",
  "a?b",
  "b?a",
  "b?b",
  "a??a",
  "a??b",
  "b??a",
  "b??b",
  "aa?",
  "ba?",
  "a?bb",
  "?bb?",
  "??abb",
  "a?b?aa",
  "ab???bb?",
  "aa?bb"
]


for s in strs:
  _solve = solve(s)
  _f = f(s)
  print("%s\n%s, %s, %s, %s\n" % (s, is_valid(_f), is_valid(_solve), _solve, _f))


import random

def get_random(n):
  char = 'x'
  count = 0
  out = []
  not_c = lambda c: 'a' if c == 'b' else 'b'

  for _ in range(n):
    c = ['a', 'b'][int(random.random() * 2)]
    if c != char:
      out.append(c)
      char, count = c, 1
    elif count == 2:
      out.append(not_c(c))
      char, count = not_c(c), 1
    else:
      out.append(c)
      count += 1

  for i in range(n):
     if int(random.random() * 2):
      out[i] = '?'

  return ''.join(out)

num_tests = 1000
n = 20

print("Starting random tests...")

for _ in range(num_tests):
  s = get_random(n)
  _solve = solve(s)
  _f = f(s)
  valid_solve = is_valid(_solve)
  valid_f = is_valid(_f)
  if not valid_f or not valid_solve:
    print(s, valid_f, valid_solve, _f, _solve)
    break

print("Done testing")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python solution and test function:**

```
import re
import random

def char_reverse(c: str) -> str:
    if c=="a":
        return "b"
    return "a"

def contiguous(chars: str,i: int,**kwargs) -> str:
    route = kwargs.get("route")
    if i<1 and route=="left":
        return "yy"
    try:
        if route=="left":
            if i-2>=0:
                return str(chars[i-2])+str(chars[i-1])
            else:
                if i-1==0:
                    return str(chars[i-1])
                else:
                    return "yy"
        if route=="right":
            if i+1<len(chars)-1:
                return str(chars[i+1])+str(chars[i+2])
            else:
                return str(chars[i+1])
    except:
        return "yy"

def char_check(chars: list, i: int) -> str:
    left = contiguous(chars,i,route="left")
    right = contiguous(chars,i,route="right")
    #print(left[-1],right[0])
    if left[-1]==right[0]:
        return char_reverse(right[0])
    if left=="aa" and right=="bb": #aa?bb => X, undefined
        return "X"
    if left=="bb" and right=="aa": #bb?aa => X, undefined
        return "X"
    if left=="ba" and right=="ab":
        return "b"
    if left=="ab" and right=="ba":
        return "a"
    if left=="aa":
        return "b"
    if left=="bb":
        return "a"
    if right=="aa":
        return "b"
    if right=="bb":
        return "a"
    return "a"


def main(string: str) -> str:
    regex = r"\?"
    match = re.finditer(regex, string) 
    indices = [m.start(0) for m in match]
    list_str = list(string)
    for i in indices:
        list_str[i] = char_check(list_str,i)
    new_str = "".join(list_str)
    print("old_str",string)
    print("new_str",new_str)
    return new_str

### TEST ###

def test(string: str) -> str:
    if "aaa" in string:
        return False
    if "bbb" in string:
        return False
    if "X" in string:
        match = re.finditer(r"X", string) 
        indices = [m.start(0) for m in match]
        for ti in indices:
            left = contiguous(string,ti,route="left")
            right = contiguous(string,ti,route="right")
            print(left,right)
            if left!="aa" and left!="bb":
                return False
            if right!="aa" and right!="bb":
                return False
    return True

def test_create_rand_string() -> str:
    TEST_MAX_LENGTH = 150 # up to ∞
    TEST_MIN_LENGTH = 1
    string = ""
    p_char = ""
    char_list = ["a","b","?"]
    for r in range(random.randint(TEST_MIN_LENGTH,TEST_MAX_LENGTH)):
        c = random.choice(char_list)
        if len(string)>1:
            p_char = string[-1]
        if c!=p_char or c=="?":
            string += c
    return string


for i in range(10000):
    string = test_create_rand_string()
    result = test(main(string))
    if result==False:
        print("error")
        quit()
    print("Test: %i" % i,result)

### TEST ###
```